# Difference Between Interface and Class

Tags: c#, class, interface

As the title states i want to know the difference between using the class like this

```
public class Account
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

and using and Interface like this

```
public class Account : IAccount
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public interface IAccount
{
    string Username { get; set; }
    string Password { get; set; }
}
```

I am really confused as i find interface is useless as all i can do with it can be done only using Class, Hence, i need someone to clarify things for me.

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271104/class-vs-interface. Just remember google is your friend

Comment: I'm going to type up an example.. but really, this sort of question is covered in any tutorial/book..

Comment: You seem to have a grasp on the situation.  Interfaces are a contract.  Classes are an implementation of the contract.

Comment: Nevermind.. that link is better than what I was gonna type :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

An interface is a *contract*: it specifies what members (methods and properties) a class implementing the interface *must* have. But because it is only a contract, it has no implementations for any of its members. A class can implement zero, one or multiple interfaces.

In contrast: a *class* is a... well... class of objects (like in taxonomy). For example, an `Animal` is a class of living things, and a `Giraffe` is a class of animals. Inheritance expresses this relationship: an `Giraffe` *is an* `Animal` when `Giraffe` inherits from `Animal`. It can do anything an animal can do, and more. It can provide implementations for its members, and in .NET a class will inherit from exactly one other class (which is `Object` unless specified otherwise).

So, if you want to express that your class adheres to one or more contracts: use *interfaces*. However, you cannot provide an implementation. If you want to express that your class *is* something, extend a base class. In that case you can provide an implementation, but you can extend only *one* base class.

---

For a concrete example:

A linked list, an array list, a stack and a dictionary have something in common: they represent a collection of elements. But their implementations are completely different. The only thing they have in common is the contract they adhere to: `ICollection`. This means your classes can ask for a collection, *any collection*: anything that implements `ICollection`, regardless of its implementation.

On the other hand: a car, a motorcycle and a truck also have something in common: they are wheeled vehicles. But they have more in common than that: they all have a motor, they all spin their tires to go forward. Essentially, they are members of the `Vehicle` class of objects, and can share (part of) their implementation. However, while a `Truck` may be a `Vehicle` *and* a `CargoCarrier`, you cannot express this in C#.

Comment: So basically, where C++ can have multiple base classes, C# can't and solve this by using Interfaces that are basically a pure virtual C++ class, correct?

Answer (score 16):

Basically:

> An interface provides a `contract` specifying how to talk to an object, but not the specifics of how that object handles that request (apart from parameters and return types etc)

And:

> A class (especially an abstract class) provides both the information on how to talk to an object, but in some cases the actual implementation (think overriding a method of a base class).

Interfaces allow you to define a common form of communicating between objects, without caring about the specifics of how they do the things.

An example would be logging:

```
public interface ILog
{
   void WriteMessage(string message);
}

public class ConsoleLogger : ILog
{
   public void WriteMessage(string message)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(message);
   }
}

public class MessageBoxLogger : ILog
{
   public void WriteMessage(string message)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(message);
   }
}

public void DoSomethingInteresting(ILog logger)
{
   logger.WriteMessage("I'm doing something interesting!");
}
```

Because both `ConsoleLogger` and `MessageBoxLogger` implement the `ILog` interface (the `WriteMessage` method, any part of code can take an `ILog` without ever needing to know what it actually does, they only care that it does **something** - in this case, writing a log message.

So in the code above, either a `ConsoleLogger` or `MessageBoxLogger` could be supplied to `DoSomethingInteresting` it doesn't matter at all because `ILog` "knows" how to talk to that object.