# Concrete class which inherites a generic interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I want to have a generic interface which has a property that is the used as the Id property of the derived classes.

I wrote the interface like below:

```
interface IEntity<T>
{
    T Id { get; set; }
}
```

and the derived classes can use it like below:

```
public class Employee : IEntity<int>
{
    // don't need to define Id property
    // public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Document : IEntity<string> { ... }
```

Unfortunately, the compiler nags this error:

> 'Employee' does not implement interface member 'IEntity.Id'

What did i do wrong? thanks.

***Edit:***
While the accepted answer solves the problem, the @dbc comments helped me to achieve  my goal, if i changed the `interface IEntity` to `abstract class IEntity` it doesn't need to implement the Id property in the derived class.

Comment: You have to implement `int Id` in `Employee : IEntity<int>`. Interface is a contract that assures others that `Employee` has `Id` property. You have to implement it.

Comment: Isn't there a method that doesn't need to implement that Id??? I created `IEntity` to reduce coding Id property in  every entity class

Comment: In that case you'll need an abstract base class `Entity` which implements the interface by defining the Id property from the contract. The Employee class can derive from that base class

Comment: You seem unsure of the difference between implementing an interface and deriving from a base class.  You might check out [Difference Between Interface and Class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15857982), [How to decide between an Interface or Base Class for an new implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15583896) or [What is the difference between an interface and abstract class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1913098).

Comment: Problem with abstract class will be, that you can inherit only from one class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing inheritance and interface implementation.

When an interface inherits another interface, the members are inherited, and you do not repeat them:

```
interface IEntity<T>
{
    T Id { get; set; }     // necessary code for 'get' and 'set' not present (yet)
}
interface IEmployee : IEntity<int>
{
    // don't need to repeat Id property
    // it is inherited
}
```

Similarly when a class inherits another class:

```
class Entity<T>
{
    public T Id { get; set; }     // automatic code for 'get' and 'set' exists here
}
class Employee : Entity<int>
{
    // don't need to repeat Id property
    // it is inherited
}
```

The base class may be made `abstract` if you want to make sure only derived classes are instantiated.

But when a class (or a struct) *implements* and interface, every member of the interface must be implemented in some way. Usually by a public member of that class or struct. (That public member may be inherited from a base class!) Or, occasionally, by an *explicit* interface implementation.

An interface has no bodies, just signatures. For example the `get` and `set` accessors of the `Id` property must have some body to make sense. When you write `T Id { get; set; }` in an interface, there are no bodies of the accessors. But when you write `T Id { get; set; }` in a class (or struct), and there is no `abstract` or `extern` modifier, the semicolons have another meaning; then the compiler while auto-generate the necessary accessor bodies (and also auto-generate a field which is used by the accessors).

Answer (score 1):

As in interface, ALL methods must be implemented!

Properties are nothing more than just methods, which have to be implemented when defined in interface: `int Id { get; set; }`.

Comment: Yep, the properties are nothing but special methods. the interface properties just declare whether they are readonly or read-write. The concrete implementation must provide definition for it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/interface-properties

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement interface for every class - just like mentioned earlier:

```
interface IEntity<T>
{
    T Id { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : IEntity<int>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```